# Maven. Adding maven repository for activiti

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, activiti, repository

The problem is that I'm trying to make somelike the helloworld with Activiti but I have an error here

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
  <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
  <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
  <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

the error is the following: '`Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.1   pom.xml /IllMakeThisTestApp line 29 Maven Dependency Problem`

Trying to resolve it I've found the following recomendation [here:](http://activiti.org/community.html)  "The download contains all the libraries that you need to work with Activiti. But for developers that prefer to use Maven, add the following reposiory"

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>Alfresco Maven Repository</id>
    <url>https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

But where shall I place it? To the file called settings.ini placed in M2_HOME/conf? This file is full of comments with no any sign of repositories. So I have no idea how to do this and ask you for help

Comment: Put in the the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place that in your `pom.xml` - see the [Maven reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) on the subject:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"...
    ...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Alfresco Maven Repository</id>
            ...
```

You will only need to tinker with the Maven config if you need to setup a mirror for the repo, eg. in case your organisation has it's own Nexus/other repo mirroring the outside "world".

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

You can place right under project. For example

```
<project>
....
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

In default maven will try to download all the artifacts from [maven central](http://repo.maven.apache.org/). You can add any number of added repositories using tag given above. Alfresco is yet another open maven repository.